# Organizing names by last name with three of the same surnames (C++)?

Tags: c++

I have an assignment to sort a list of names alphabetically by last name. However, there are three names with the same surname and I can't get the first names to alphabetize with the surnames. Have to code own bubble sort or other sorting algorithm. I chose bubblesort because it's one of the only ones we've learned so far. Any help is appreciated. Everything works except the correct assortment.

Here is my code:

```
// my name
// Program 6
// This program will show a list of names in a variety of orders.


#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int size = 25;

void showContacts_FNLN(string fnameArray[], string lnameArray[], int size);
void showContacts_LNFN(string lnameArray[], string fnameArray[], int size);
void reverseContacts_FNLN(string fnameArray[], string lnameArray[], int size);
void reverseContacts_LNFN(string fnameArray[], string lnameArray[], int size);
void searchLasname(string lnameArray[], string fnameArray[], int size);
void searchFirname(string fnameArray[], string lnameArray[], int size);
void bubbleSort(string lnameArray[], string fnameArray[], int size);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int count = 0;
    int ans;
    ifstream nameData;
    string lnameArray[size];
    string fnameArray[size];
    string lname, fname;

    nameData.open("names.txt");

    while(nameData >> fname >> lname)
    {
        fnameArray[count] = fname;
        lnameArray[count] = lname;
        count ++;
    }

    bubbleSort(lnameArray, fnameArray, size);

    while(ans != 9)
    {
        cout << "What would you like to do?" << endl;
        cout << "1) display contacts by first name and last name" << endl;
        cout << "2) display contacts by last name and first name" << endl;
        cout << "3) display contacts by first name and last name in reverse order" << endl;
        cout << "4) display contacts by last name and first name in reverse order" << endl;
        cout << "5) search for contact by last name" << endl;
        cout << "6) search for contact by first name" << endl;
        cout << "9) exit" << endl;
        cout << "Enter: ";
        cin >> ans;
        cout << endl;

        switch(ans)
        {
            case 1: showContacts_FNLN(fnameArray, lnameArray, size); // shows contacts in FN-LN order
                break;
            case 2: showContacts_LNFN(lnameArray, fnameArray, size); // LN-FN order
                break;
            case 3: reverseContacts_FNLN(fnameArray, lnameArray, size); // reversed FN-LN order
                break;
            case 4: reverseContacts_LNFN (fnameArray, lnameArray, size); // reversed LN-FN order
                break;
            case 5: searchLasname(lnameArray, fnameArray, size); // searches based on LN
                break;
            case 6: searchFirname(fnameArray, lnameArray, size); // searches based on FN
                break;
            case 9: cout << "Goodbye!" << endl;
                break;
        }
    }

    nameData.close();

    return 0;
}

void showContacts_FNLN(string fnameArray[], string lnameArray[], int size)
{
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        cout << fnameArray[i] << " " << lnameArray[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void showContacts_LNFN(string lnameArray[], string fnameArray[], int size)
{
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        cout << lnameArray[i] << ", " << fnameArray[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void reverseContacts_FNLN(string fnameArray[], string lnameArray[], int size)
{
    for(int i=(size-1); i>=0; i--)
    {
        cout << fnameArray[i] << " " << lnameArray[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void reverseContacts_LNFN(string fnameArray[], string lnameArray[], int size)
{
    for(int i=(size-1); i>=0; i--)
    {
        cout << lnameArray[i] << ", " << fnameArray[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void searchLasname(string lnameArray[], string fnameArray[], int size)
{
    int c = 0;
    string slnam;
    cout << "Enter a last name: ";
    cin >> slnam;

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        if(slnam==lnameArray[i])
        {
            cout << lnameArray[i] << ", " << fnameArray[i] << endl;
            c++;
        }
    }
    if (c == 0)
    {
        cout << "There is no match.";
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void searchFirname(string fnameArray[], string lnameArray[], int size)
{
    int c = 0;
    string sfnam;
    cout << "Enter a first name: ";
    cin >> sfnam;

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        if(sfnam==fnameArray[i])
        {
            cout << fnameArray[i] << " " << lnameArray[i] << endl;
            c++;
        }
    }
    if (c==0)
    {
        cout << "There is no match." << endl;
    }
    cout << endl; 
}

void bubbleSort(string lnameArray[], string fnameArray[], int size)
{
    string tmp, tmp2;
    //int count=0;


    for( int i = 1; i <= size - 1; i++ )
    {
        for( int j = 0; j < size - i; j++ )
        {
            //count++;
            if( lnameArray[j] > lnameArray[j+1] )
            {
                tmp = lnameArray[j];
                lnameArray[j] = lnameArray[j+1];
                lnameArray[j+1] = tmp;
            }
            if(lnameArray[j] == lnameArray[j+1])
            {
                if(fnameArray[j] > fnameArray[j+1])
                {
                    tmp = lnameArray[j];
                    lnameArray[j] = lnameArray[j+1];
                    lnameArray[j+1] = tmp;

                    tmp2 = fnameArray[j];
                    fnameArray[j] = fnameArray[j+1];
                    fnameArray[j+1] = tmp2;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //cout << "count = " << count << endl;
}
```

Comment: The sorting criterion you seek doesn't only involve surnames.   If surnames are different, sorting on them is fine.   But if multiple names nave equal surname, order them by given name.    Beyond that, your question is unclear - you say you can't use `#include`, but have done so three times.

Comment: It will be a whole lot easier if you extract your comparison criterion to a separate function.

Comment: @Peter, at some point in typing this question, I forgot to type the other part to the #include. Can't remember what it was going to be... but thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
void bubbleSort(string lnameArray[], string fnameArray[], int size)
{
    for( int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++ )
    {
        for( int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++ )
        {
            string name1 = lnameArray[j] + fnameArray[j];
            string name2 = lnameArray[j + 1] + fnameArray[j + 1];
            if(name1.compare(name2) > 0)
            {
                string tmp = lnameArray[j];
                lnameArray[j] = lnameArray[j + 1];
                lnameArray[j + 1] = tmp;

                tmp = fnameArray[j];
                fnameArray[j] = fnameArray[j + 1];
                fnameArray[j + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of having another 'if' for those that have similar last names, I combined the last name and the first name instead then used it for comparison.

I also noticed in your code in `for( int j = 0; j < size - i; j++ )` that you forgot to add `- 1` after `size - i`. Once `j == size - i - 1` (assuming that `i == 0` currently) then you use `j + 1` to access an index, this will cause a segmentation fault since you're accessing an index beyond its range.

Answer (score 0):

Your sort doesn't work because you change the position of the last names only (except for the case where two last names are equal.)

You should use a `struct` to store this information together in one array. Then you can simplify your code a lot:

```
struct Person {
    Person() = default;
    Person(string firstname, string lastname) : firstname(std::move(firstname)), lastname(std::move(lastname)) {}
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
};

void showContacts_FNLN(Person personArray[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << personArray[i].firstname << " " << personArray[i].lastname << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void bubbleSort(Person personArray[], int size) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= size - 1; i++) {
        // The condition must size - i - 1 because otherwise personArray[j+1] is faulty
        for (int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++) {
            if (personArray[j].lastname > personArray[j+1].lastname
                || (personArray[j].lastname == personArray[j+1].lastname &&
                    personArray[j].firstname > personArray[j+1].firstname)) {
                auto tmp = std::move(personArray[j]);
                personArray[j] = std::move(personArray[j+1]);
                personArray[j+1] = std::move(tmp);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int count = 0;
    ifstream nameData;
    Person personArray[size];
    string lname, fname;

    nameData.open("names.txt");

    while(nameData >> fname >> lname) {
        personArray[count] = Person(fname, lname);
        count++;
    }
    nameData.close();

    bubbleSort(personArray, size);

    showContacts_FNLN(personArray, size);

    return 0;
}
```

I removed some non-essential parts from this example to keep it very short but you should get the idea. (Note that my code makes use of C++11 move semantics, if this confuses you, just remove them.)

Some more suggestions:

- Do not use `using namespace std;`. (The internet will tell you why.)
- If you can, use `std::array`, which eliminates the need to always pass the size of the arrays and allows you to use a C++11 range for loop.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I can't use the concepts you've mentioned because my prof has not shown them to us.